# How to use store credit for a cart in magento 2 api

Tags: magento-enterprise, sales-order, rest-api, magento-2.2.5, store-credit

Magento version: EE 2.2.5

I have a customer with **store credit**.

I created cart using

```
rest/default/V1/customers/:customerId/carts
```

And I added items to that cart using

```
rest/default/V1/carts/:cartId/items
```

And added shipping information using

```
rest/default/V1/carts/:cartId/shipping-information
```

But i need to apply **store credit** for this order using API.

- How that can be done?
- which API I have to hit ?
- Or is there something i have to add in request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Customer balance(store credit) operations**

```
rest/V1/carts/mine/balance/apply
```

- `method - POST`

Comment: how can you check the customer balance?